# Python Memory Leak - Scikit-learn + Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, memory-management, memory-leaks

Can't seem to fix my memory leak, I managed to replicate it easily. I seems to happen when i use sklearn GaussianMixture multiple times, while varying the the number of training pixels I give it.

This code **does not** leak:

```
import os, psutil
from sklearn import mixture
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

process = psutil.Process()

def get_size():
    process = psutil.Process()
    return process.memory_info().rss  / 100000 

sizes = []
for _ in range(100):
    training_pixels = np.random.random((500000,3))
    gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(
        n_components=5, covariance_type="full", random_state=40
    ).fit(training_pixels)

    size = get_size()
    sizes.append(size)

    del gmm, training_pixels


plt.plot(sizes)
```

[image: Weird oscillations, but why not]

This code, however, leaks (notice how the number of training pixels is never larger than in the previous example, it can only be smaller or equal to 500000):

```
import os, psutil
from sklearn import mixture
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

process = psutil.Process()

def get_size():
    process = psutil.Process()
    return process.memory_info().rss  / 100000 

sizes = []
for _ in range(100):
    training_pixels = np.random.random((np.random.randint(200000,500000),3))
    gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(
        n_components=5, covariance_type="full", random_state=40
    ).fit(training_pixels)

    size = get_size()
    sizes.append(size)

    del gmm, training_pixels

plt.plot(sizes)
```

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: I think it would be more suited to open an issue on the sklearn bug tracker for the developers to fix the issue. It would be good to check with valgrind if the problem is directly in sklearn or another dependent library internally. Valgrind can also tell if the target leak is a true one (unreachable) or not.

Comment: Does it stabilize if you do more iterations? It might possibly be a fragmentation issue of the allocator due to the variable array size. Since the array is pretty big the allocator may not even stabilize using inefficient free-lists. The OS allocator is expected to stabilize because pages should be reused (not 100% sure with huge pages though).

Comment: I can suggest two things which you can try out

i. use the garbage collector, to help clear out objects which are not needed

ii. freeing up the memory by setting training_pixels = None before deleting it.

Comment: Only partly related comment: the `del` statement should have not much of an effect here. The variables are overwritten in the next iteration and un-referenced object get collected by the garbage collector anyway.

Comment: Thanks guys, I posted the issue on github :)